# Wrong tooltip for greyed out edit link on locked meta post

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, tooltips, locked-questions

When I was trying to edit a locked question on a per-site meta, I noticed the edit link is disabled, so I hovered over it, and was surprised to see the generic tooltip:

> [image]

Or in words:

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

I have full edit privileges on that per-site meta, the real reason I can't edit is because the question is locked.

Can the tooltip please be fixed to reflect the real reason why a post can't be edited on per-site meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you're absolutely right. I've rearranged the code so that the correct reason should fall out; this should be available at some point later today (whenever the revision bottom-left says something higher than 2017.2.2.24897). Thanks - good eyes.

Comment: Well, credits go to Joel... ;) (I'm not really active on per-meta sites usually, and this bug doesn't affect MSE :))